Diode Circuit Input-Output Plot Question

My attempt:
When V_in is very positive, the diode is off, and V_out = R1/(R1+R2) * V_in
When V_in is very negative, the diode is on and so: V_in + V_D,ON {constant voltage model} = V_out
But I am having difficulty in determining the point between the two regions. I.e. how to get (1+R1/R2)*V_D,on?
Source: Fundamentals of Microelectronic Circuits By Behzard Razavi: https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Microelectronics-Behzad-Razavi/dp/0471478466 {First edition}.
Chapter 3, Diodes.


I am having difficulty in determining the point between the two
regions

With D1 omitted you have this: -

So, it boils down to equating \$V_{R2}\$ to the forward volt drop of the diode and uncovering what the input voltage is that makes it so.
That will be the "turning point".

Thank you! You made it much simpler than the solution present in the book, in my opinion.

Andy already provided the answer.Please see the detailed explanation.


+1 but I would consider the voltage from anode to cathode of diode to include the minus sign.

Other people have presented good ways to get the result. I'm going to present another method which is maybe not optimal, but it works.
You can find the intersection between two lines for the transition point.

For low input voltage, you have:
$$V_{out1} = V_{in} + V_{D,\text{ON}} $$
For high input voltage, you have:
$$ V_{out2} = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} V_{in}$$
So, the intersection point should be:
$$ V_{out1} = V_{out2} $$
Or:
$$ V_{in} + V_{D,\text{ON}} = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} V_{in} $$
Solving this, you get:
$$ V_{in} = -\left(1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2}\right) V_{D,\text{ON}} $$

Nice! That is actually an interesting technique to be used in more complex circuits! Thanks.
